# PowerShell - Get Average Memory Usage of Server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running an instance of Windows Server 2012 R2 and would like to get the average memory usage of my server.

To get the CPU usage, I use

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | select LoadPercentage  |fl
```

and to get the average CPU usage, I have

```
Get-WmiObject win32_processor | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average
```

How do I do the same thing with memory usage?

Answer (score 4):

You want the Win32_OperatingSystem namespace, and it's TotalVisibleMemorySize (physical memory), FreePhysicalMemory, TotalVirtualMemorySize, and FreeVirtualMemory properties.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |%{"Total Physical Memory: {0}KB`nFree Physical Memory : {1}KB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2}KB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3}KB" -f $_.totalvisiblememorysize, $_.freephysicalmemory, $_.totalvirtualmemorysize, $_.freevirtualmemory}
```

That will spit back:

```
Total Physical Memory: 4079572KB
Free Physical Memory : 994468KB
Total Virtual Memory : 8157280KB
Free Virtual Memory  : 3448916KB
```

I'm sure you can do the math if you want to get Used instead of Free.

**Edit:** Your CPULoad Average isn't really an average of anything. Case in point:

```
For($a=1;$a -lt 30;$a++){
    Get-WmiObject win32_processor|ForEach{
        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
            'Average' = $_ | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select -expand Average
            'Current' = $_ | select -expand LoadPercentage
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}
```

Results:

```
Average                                          CPU Load
-------                                          --------
2                                                 2
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
5                                                 5
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
0                                                 0
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
1                                                 1
2                                                 2
4                                                 4
0                                                  
1                                                 1
7                                                 7
24                                                24
1                                                 1
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get an average here like with CPU usage?

Comment: Average over time? Not that I know of. Of coarse, you aren't really getting an average over time with the CPU load either. You're getting the average of a single result of LoadPercent.

Comment: I am confused.  How can it be an average if it's a single result?

Comment: It runs the Average formula against a single item array basically. So Sum(LoadPercent)/1 is essentially all it's doing.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble on that one.

Comment: Better formatting for the memory, IMO, if you do this: Get-WmiObject win32_OperatingSystem |%{"Total Physical Memory: {0:N0}MB`nFree Physical Memory : {1:N0}MB`nTotal Virtual Memory : {2:N0}MB`nFree Virtual Memory  : {3:N0}MB" -f ($_.totalvisiblememorysize/1KB), ($_.freephysicalmemory/1KB), ($_.totalvirtualmemorysize/1KB), ($_.freevirtualmemory/1KB)}

Answer (score 0):

If you want an average over a period of time you could use performance counters

```
### Get available memory in MB ###
$interval = 1 #seconds
$maxsamples = 5
$memorycounter = (Get-Counter "\Memory\Available MBytes" -maxsamples $maxsamples -sampleinterval $interval | 
select -expand countersamples | measure cookedvalue -average).average
### Memory Average Formatting ###
$freememavg = "{0:N0}" -f $memorycounter
### Get total Physical Memory & Calculate Percentage ###
$physicalmemory = (Get-WMIObject -class Win32_PhysicalMemory | Measure-Object -Property capacity -Sum).Sum / 1mb
$physicalmemory - $freememavg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function Get-ADtop {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [String]$ComputerName,
    [String]$Sort = "none",  
    [String]$BaseDN = "OU=systems,DC=domain,DC=com",  # Edit Default Base DN
    [String]$SampleTime = 2
)
If ($ComputerName) {
    $Computers = $ComputerName
} else {
    $Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $BaseDN -EA SilentlyContinue | % {$_.Name}
}
$DataSet = @()
$Targets = @()
ForEach ($Comp in $Computers) {
    If (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Comp -Count 1 -Quiet -TimeToLive 1 -EA SilentlyContinue) {
        If (!(Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp win32_OperatingSystem -EA SilentlyContinue)) { break }
        $Targets += $Comp
    }
}
$CompCount = $Computers | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count}
$DeadCount = $CompCount - ($Targets | Measure-Object | % {$_.Count})
If (!($DeadCount -eq 0)) {
    Write-Host "`n$DeadCount unavailable computers removed"
}
Write-Host "`nGathering realtime CPU/MEM/DISK Usage data from $CompCount computers..."
ForEach ($Comp in $Targets) {
    $proc = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class win32_processor -EA SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average | % {$_.Average / 100}).ToString("P")
    $mem = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp win32_OperatingSystem -EA SilentlyContinue 
    $mem = (($mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $mem.FreePhysicalMemory) / $mem.TotalVisibleMemorySize).ToString("P")
    $disk = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Comp -class Win32_LogicalDisk -filter "DriveType=3" -EA SilentlyContinue 
    $disk = (($disk.Size - $disk.FreeSpace) / $disk.Size).ToString("P")
    $Info = [pscustomobject]@{
        'Computer' = $Comp
        'CPU Usage' = $proc
        'MEM Usage' = $mem
        'Disk Usage' = $disk
    }
    $DataSet += Add-Member -InputObject $Info -TypeName Computers.CPU.Usage -PassThru    
}
Switch ($Sort) {
    "none" { $DataSet }
    "CPU" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "CPU Usage" -Descending }
    "MEM" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "MEM Usage" -Descending }
    "DISK" { $DataSet | Sort-Object -Property "DISK Usage" -Descending }
}
}
```

[More info here GitHub Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/jonretting/20da31893df25cf40cd7)